# how to open file in window on set position using autohokey from cmd/batch?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, autohotkey

I having a hard time to combine my scripts which work separately...

basicly I have a batch script with following in it:

```
START "" "mpc-hc64.exe" "video.avi"
```

this will open my video in mediaplayer. so far so good. then I had some reading on SO and SE about how to open window on set position via cmd/bat and found out in answers about [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (documentation: [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm)). so I downloaded a zip with executable and created a AHK script:

```
Run mpc-hc64.exe
WinWait, Media Player Classic Home Cinema
WinActivate
WinMove A,, 960, 0, A_ScreenWidth-960, A_ScreenHeight-29
```

this will open my mediaplayer at the right side of my screen if I run this cmd/bat:

```
AutoHotkeyU32.exe "script 1.ahk"
```

and now I would need to combine all above into one batch which if I run it thet it will open my video file in my mediaplayer and on the right side of my screen. can enyone help?

Comment: Put both commands in the same batch file.

Comment: @DavidPostill lol, like I wouldnt try that already...

Comment: So why didn't you say so in your question? What happened when you tried?

Comment: @DavidPostill well, I wouldnt ask my question here if it would work, would I... happened what is already obvious from my post... eather I can open my video in player with no possition or open my player on window position without my video. so with combo of my codes happens this: video will open in my player on almost full screen ocupation and then 2nd player will open over my first player but now vithout video however on desired position.

Comment: So fix your ahk script to act on the current player instead of opening a new one.

Comment: And please [edit] your question to include the new information.

Comment: I wont edit anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way (on official discord AHK chanel):

```
#Persistent

mpc := "C:\T4\mpc-hc 1.7.16 x64\mpc-hc64.exe"
avi := "C:\T1\scripts\avi.avi"

Run, % """" mpc """ """ avi """", , , pid

WinWaitActive, % "ahk_pid " pid
WinGet, mpc_hwnd, ID, % "ahk_pid " pid

SetTimer, CheckWindowPosition, 100

CheckWindowPosition:
    if(!WinExist("ahk_pid " pid)) {
        ExitApp
        }
    WinGetPos, x, y, width, height, % "ahk_pid " pid
    WinGet, hwnd, ID, % "ahk_pid " pid
    if(DllCall("GetParent", "Ptr", hwnd, "UInt", 3) = 0 && DllCall("GetAncestor", "Ptr", hwnd, "UInt", 3) = mpc_hwnd) {
            if(x != 960 || y != 0 || width != A_ScreenWidth - 960 || height != A_ScreenHeight - 29) {
            WinMove, % "ahk_pid " pid, , 960, 0, % A_ScreenWidth - 960, % A_ScreenHeight - 29
            }
        }
return
```

Comment: But your question states.... "*now I would need to combine all above into one batch*"..... uh..... this is just AHK script only, correct? Furthermore, just as FYI since you appear to be able to figure out things pretty well in your automation tasks [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is FREE, simple, and does not require any installs to do similar such tasks and you can compile into an executable that will run from any machine if you test properly. That's just FYI since you seem to figure out and understand logic and code pretty well in case you get time to read/review.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT the drill was that I was missing few parts in AHK script which I thought I will compensate by using cmd, but that was the wrong way of thinking. yes this is AHK-only and I call it from batch like this `AutoHotkeyU32.exe "script 1.ahk"` and all works. whit this one I've got huge help from AHK devs over AHK Official Discord, so no credit goes for me tho.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use parameters to pass the commandline argument to the script?

I didn't test this code below, but the basic concept would be to use commandline variables in both the .bat file and the .ahk file to capture what the user types on the commandline and pass it through to be executed.

**commandline**

```
C:\>launch video.avi
```

**launch.bat**

```
@echo off
AutoHotkeyU32.exe "script 1.ahk" %1
```

**script 1.ahk**

```
Run mpc-hc64.exe %1%
WinWait, Media Player Classic Home Cinema
WinActivate
WinMove A,, 960, 0, A_ScreenWidth-960, A_ScreenHeight-29
```